# How can I exclude vue2 from vue SPA created with cli, by using http-vue-loader?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, http-vue-loader

## Background

I have a SPA application created with the vue-cli. To decrease server traffic, I'd like to exclude vue2 from the webpack bundle. So, I exclude Vue and Vuetify by config.externals of vue.config.js, and core-js by babel.js.

But still remained the **vue-loader** in the bundle as occupy the right third　as follows:

[image]

I'd like to exclude this vue-loader.

## My problem

I try to use **http-vue-loader** from CDN by adding the following script in the  index.html file:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/http-vue-loader"></script>
```

And set it as externals as follow in the config.externals on the vue.config.js file as follows:

```
    config.externals({
      vue: 'Vue',
      vuetify: 'Vuetify',
      'vuetify/lib/framework': 'Vuetify',
      'httpVueLoader': 'httpVueLoader',
    })
```

Then I changed two places importing the vue file. The former is the **main.js**, which importing **App.vue** as follow:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

I've changed it as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
// import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

/*
new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
*/

Vue.use(vuetify)

import httpVueLoader from "httpVueLoader";

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    App: httpVueLoader("./App.vue")
  }
});
```

The later is **App.vue** importing **Home.vue** as follows:

```
<script>

import Home from '@/views/Home.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    Home
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
};
</script>
```

I've changed it as follows:

```
<script>

//import Home from '@/views/Home.vue'
import httpVueLoader from "httpVueLoader";
const Home = httpVueLoader('/src/views/Home.vue')
export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    Home
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
};
</script>
```

## [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...

After running test server by **yarn serve** and show on the browser, the page is just **white** and console shows that it is waiting as **[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...**

[image]

## My question

What is WDS signal? Why my app is waiting for this? How can I avoid this and my app running normally? Any suggestions are welcome.

## Reproducing Environment

A simple reproducing environment is available as https://github.com/UedaTakeyuki/http-vue-loader.